# How do you send attributes to javascript functions in svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I've got a small SVG files which is growing quite fast, and I've got this little funtion:

```
function displayName(name) {
    document.getElementById('label').firstChild.data = name;
}
```

And so each and every of my element look like this:

```xml
<ellipse id="MyElementName" onmouseover="displayName('MyElementName')"
```

So whenever my element is hovered it prints its name in a text who's id is `label`

But since I've got a few elements that can be hovered, I was wondering if there was a shortcut. Something like:

```xml
<ellipse id="MyElementName" onmouseover="displayName('$id')"
```

So I wouldn't have to copy the element name everywhere.

Is there a way to do so or do I need to copy them for all elements?

Comment: `id` is always unique in the page

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes, but I need to print the Id of the element calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use event listeners.

(The orange one has no `id` on purpose)

```js
var svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
var display = document.getElementById('display');
for (var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
  svgs[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
    displayId(e.currentTarget);
  });
  svgs[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
    clearDisplay();
  });
}

function displayId(e) {
  if (e.id) {
    display.innerHTML = e.id;
  }
}

function clearDisplay() {
  display.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" id="red">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
</svg>
<svg height="100" width="100" id="green">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="green" />
</svg>
<svg height="100" width="100" id="blue">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" />
</svg>
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="orange" />
</svg>

<div id="display"></div>
```